# Best way to parse XML in C# with regard to performance

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I want to know the best way to parse XML , i.e in terms of performance (space and time).

I have done parsing through the following methods

- With the regular "for each" loops
- With Linq
- Dot notation or lambda notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it is not easy to optimise it. However, there is one general point you should consider:

Linq-to-XML is a DOM-based parser, in that it reads the entire XML document into a model which resides in memory. All queries are executed against the DOM. For large documents, constructing the DOM can be memory and CPU intensive. Also, your Linq-to-XML queries, if written inefficiently can navigate the same tree nodes multiple times.

As an alternative, consider using a serial (SAX) parser like [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Parsers of this type do not create a memory-based model of your document, and operate in a forward-only manner, forcing you to read each element just once.

Answer (score 0):

I it is a big and complicated XML file you could try to parse it using SAX type XML parser. The SAX parser will generate an event for each of your nodes in XML file so you will not need to load the whole file into the memory. In case of a small file which should be analysed as a web response for example in your application and must be validated I will suggest you to use the DOM type XML parser.